# Verticall scroll richtextbox on the bottom [WPF]

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, scrollbar

I have a richtextbox and when is full I want automatically scroll to the bottom, It is possible? Do this with xaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [`ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx) routed event, and writing some code (for example,  `richTextBox1.ScrollToEnd()`), you may be able to do what you want.

Comment: Doing this on the ScrollChanged event does scroll to the bottom, but it effectively disables the scrollbars on the textbox.  Using the TextChanged event would work better.

Answer (score 1):

`RichTextBox` has a `ScrollToEnd` method that could be called in the Codebehind. I don't know a way to do this in XAML only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `RichTextBox` is named `Output`, attach this method to its `TextChanged` event:

```
void Output_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Output.ScrollToEnd();
}
```