# How can I make a RichTextBox scroll to the end when I add a new line?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I have several read only RichTextBox's that are used for logging output. Since they're read only they don't seem to automatically scroll when the text is updated.  I *can* use the TextChanged event to force a scroll to end, but is there not simply a way to set a property or something in the XAML so that scrolling happens like normal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verticall scroll richtextbox on the bottom \[WPF\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256129/verticall-scroll-richtextbox-on-the-bottom-wpf)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had googled for your problem and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg315209) post.
In the section "Programming the RichTextBox" author had described about getting the behavior what you had been expecting.

Please check and let me know if it is of any use.

---

I tried to reproduce your problem and came up with the following solution

```
    <Window x:Class="CheckRichTextBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="170" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox Height="100" Name="richTextBox1" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        <Button Name="btnAdd" Content="Click me to add text" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="BtnAddClick" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The code behind for the same is as below:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CheckRichTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnAddClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You had Clicked the button for adding text\n");
            richTextBox1.ScrollToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

This solves the problem of autoscroll, please check it and let me know if it is of any help.

Comment: It makes the scrollbar visible, but it still doesn't scroll to the end of the document when text is added programmatically.  Looks like I may be stuck with the TextChanged event.

Comment: @Merad How do you do it with TextChanged event?

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem using an [Interactivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) trigger and a very simple action.

The action looks like this:

```
public class ScrollToBottomAction : TriggerAction<RichTextBox>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Then in my XAML I have this:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <interactivity:ScrollToBottomAction/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work because of something to do with the blend version  being old. And I've tried what was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024034/the-type-from-assembly-is-built-with-an-older-version-of-blend-sdk-and-is-not-su with no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: `<ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="ScrollToEnd"/>` also works.

Comment: FYI - The `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace is deprecated. Use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors` instead, which includes the `TriggerAction` class.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution for wpf richtextbox autoscroll

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private bool AutoScroll = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        yourRichTextBox.Loaded += (s, e) =>
          {
              var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(yourRichTextBox, 0), 0) as ScrollViewer;
              scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += (scroller, eScroller) => ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(scroller, eScroller);
          };
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // User scroll event : set or unset autoscroll mode
        if (e.Source as ScrollViewer != null && e.ExtentHeightChange == 0)
        {   // Content unchanged : user scroll event
            if ((e.Source as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset == (e.Source as ScrollViewer).ScrollableHeight)
            {   // Scroll bar is in bottom
                // Set autoscroll mode
                AutoScroll = true;
            }
            else
            {   // Scroll bar isn't in bottom
                // Unset autoscroll mode
                AutoScroll = false;
            }
        }

        // Content scroll event : autoscroll eventually
        if (AutoScroll && e.ExtentHeightChange != 0 && e.Source as ScrollViewer != null)
        {   // Content changed and autoscroll mode set
            // Autoscroll
            (e.Source as ScrollViewer).ScrollToVerticalOffset((e.Source as ScrollViewer).ExtentHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in C#

Put the RichTextBox in a ScrollViewer like this:

scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

scrollViewer.Content = rTextBox;

Then add the scrollViewer to the Grid or whatever you are using.

RootGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);

(This is in C# but could all be done in XAML as well.)

Then use C# code like this to make it scroll to the bottom when you add text:

```
rTextBox.AppendText(str);
scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
RichTextBox.AppendText("String")
RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
```

When I was adding to RichTextBox.text, ScrollToCaret() does not work.

```
RichTextBox.text = RichTextBox.text + "String"
RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
```

Comment: `ScrollToCaret` is for a WinForms `RichTextBox`, not a WPF one. There's a question about that here: [Rich Text box scroll to the bottom when new data is written to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416608/rich-text-box-scroll-to-the-bottom-when-new-data-is-written-to-it)