# ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries causes weird errors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

Inside my WPF Application I am including a ResourceDictionary from another Project.

```
<Application x:Class="namespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- This Line causes an Error -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Commons;Component/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

> Metadata override and base metadata must be of the same type or derived type.

The solution builds successful and runs.

Restarting Visual Studio doesn't fix it.

Cut and Paste the `<ResourceDictionary Source="..." />` line causes another error as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35566198/4099159) in the Comments: 
`Value Cannot be Null. Parameter Name: item`. Restarting Visual Studio will then bring back the old error.

Sadly I haven't found out how to reproduce this error, I can only tell you something more about the environment im using:

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

And allthough I doubt, those are associated with my problem, here my installed Plugins:

- Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.1
- GitExtensions Version 2.49.03

Comment: `Generic.xaml` should be located in Themes folder (read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228915/1997232) answer). There are 2 more ways to specify Uri, try `Source="/YourAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"` and `Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"`. Don't ask me why, but in certain cases one or another way will not work.

Comment: @sinatr I have tried your idea and it worked. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

**Sinatr**'s comment hinted me to read more about theming.

## `ThemeInfo`

Inside of a Custom Control Library theres automatically created a `ThemeInfoAttribute` inside `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly:ThemeInfo(
 ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                          //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
                          // or application resource dictionaries)
 ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                   //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
                                   // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

#### Parameters

As it states in the autogenerated comments, the **first parameter** is to determine wheter there exist or where to find Theme specific resource dictionaries.
The **second parameter** defines wheter there exist or where to find the generic `ResourceDictionary` (`Generic.xaml`).

## `ResourceDictionaryLocation`-Enumeration

The `ResourceDictionaryLocation`-Enumeration itself is used to specify the location of those dictionaries.

#### `ResourceDictionaryLocation.None`

> No theme dictionaries exist.

#### `ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly`

> Theme dictionaries exist in the assembly that defines the types being themed.
> **This** expects the `ResourceDictionary` to be located in a `/Themes`-Folder. Explanation later.

#### `ResourceDictionaryLocation.ExternalAssembly`

> Theme dictionaries exist in assemblies external to the one defining the types being themed.

I am not going to explain how this works.

#### Why `/Themes`-Folder

*Sadly I couldn't find too much about this. If someone has some more info please share.*

Have you ever wondered, how styles of a lookless control are being applied?

If one created a lookless Control, he did as follows:

```
public class MyControl : ControlTemplate
{
    static MyControl() 
    {
        // This tells WPF to search for a Style for this type
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl)), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }
}
```

In short, Ressources in WPF are located, by searching up the *`Logical-Tree`*, then inside `Application`'s Resources and finally inside sth. they call *`System-Area`* (this is my translation from German, if you know a better one pls tell).

So depending on `ThemeInfo`, `MyControl` propably had its Style inside a `ResourceDictionary` inside the `/Themes`-Folder, eg. `/Themes/Generic.xaml`. And **that** tells WPF to add the Ressources to the *`System-Area`* which finally results in automatically resolving the appropriate style.

Somewhere inside `/Themes/Generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
            ..
            </ControlTemplate/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

> That's why the above `ThemeInfoAttribute` requires `Generic.xaml` to be located in a `/Themes`-Folder. - And somehow, even if in my case the *`System-Area`*-Functionality isn't even used for this generic file, this causes those errors. But I wasn't able to find out why.

Sources:

- [ThemeInfoAttribute Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.themeinfoattribute.themeinfoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ResourceDictionaryLocation Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionarylocation(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Windows Presentation Foundation - Das Umfassende Handbuch, Rheinwerk Computing Version 4