# Compatibility issue with Expression.Blend.Sdk 1.0.2 System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, prism

I'm developing a WPF with Visual Studio 2015 Community, C#, **.NET Framework 4.6.1** and Prism.Wpf 6.1.0, Prism.Core 6.1.0 and Expression.Blend.Sdk 1.0.2.

I'm following: [Implement a confirmation dialog in WPF using MVVM and Prism](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/04/20/implement-a-confirmation-dialog-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-prism/) tutorial.

I have added Interaction triggers to a Windows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Helpers"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="604.62" Width="655.879">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <!-- Trigger listening for the "Raised" event on the source object (of type IInteractionRequest) -->
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Raised" SourceObject="{Binding ConfirmationInteractionRequest}">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <local:StartBatchWindowAction />
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
```

I get the following error on `<local:StartBatchWindowAction />`:

> the type from assembly is built with an older version of blend sdk and
>   is not supported in a windows presentation foundation 4 project

This is `StartBatchWindowAction` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace TRZ_Domino.Helpers
{
    public class StartBatchWindowAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I have done all the steps in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32024035/68571) but when I tried to compile `PrismLibrary_Wpf` and get another error:

> IServiceLocator not found.

How can I fix this problem?

I have used ILSpy to check that dll and this is what I got:

> //
>   D:\Development\packages\Expression.Blend.Sdk.1.0.2\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
>   // System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>  
>  // Global type:
>   
>  // Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
>  //
>   Runtime: .NET 4.0
>  
>  using System;
>  using
>   System.Diagnostics;
>  using System.Reflection;
>  using
>   System.Resources;
>  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
>   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>  using
>   System.Runtime.Versioning;
>  using System.Security;
>  using
>   System.Security.Permissions;
>  using System.Windows.Markup;
>   
>  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.5.0.0")]
>  [assembly:
>   CLSCompliant(true)]
>  [assembly: Debuggable]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyCompany("Microsoft Corporation")]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyCopyright("Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.")]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyDescription("System.Windows.Interactivity")]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyFileVersion("3.0.40218.0")]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyProduct("System.Windows.Interactivity")]
>  [assembly:
>   AssemblyTitle("System.Windows.Interactivity")]
>  [assembly:
>   NeutralResourcesLanguage]
>  [assembly:
>   CompilationRelaxations(8)]
>  [assembly:
>   InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UnitTests,
>   PublicKey=...")]
>  [assembly:
>   InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.Expression.BlendSDK.UnitTests,
>   PublicKey=...")]
>  [assembly:
>   RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
>  [assembly:
>   ComVisible(false)]
>  [assembly:
>   TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName =
>   "")]
>  [assembly:
>   XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity",
>   "System.Windows.Interactivity")]
>  [assembly:
>   XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity",
>   "i")]
>  [assembly: SecurityPermission(8, SkipVerification =
>   true)]
>  [module: UnverifiableCode]

I have removed Prism from the project and I get the same error, so this is not a problem with Prism.

[Github](https://github.com/VansFannel/WpfApplicationModalWindow) source code.

Comment: I've same problems and didn't manage to solve them. Have tried all suggestions that I've found. Sometimes the designer shows up without any errors about "older version", but then they come again.