# Modal windows on WPF or UserControl to simulate it?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF with C#, .NET Framework 4.6.1, Prism 6.1.0 and Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I'm new in WPF and I'm having a lot of problems to follow MVVM pattern.

I have asked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066275/wpf-blend-sdk-compatibility-issue-with-system-windows-interactivity), but it seems that it doesn't have an answer. And searching on Internet I'm finding solutions to my problem but they are very complex.

Is it correct to create an `UserControl` to simulate a blocking window and add it to my current window?

Or maybe, it's better to have two windows, and open it following like they did in this [tutorial](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/04/20/implement-a-confirmation-dialog-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-prism/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801681/good-or-bad-practice-for-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the `UC` approach and not mess around with Windows all over the place,
chances are there will be more than one window, then you would have to check which one should be on top and sometimes your application will hide the popup for no apparent reason.
You could place that User Control in your MainWindow.xaml and catch every event or message from your application and display it to the user.
From maintenance point of view `UserControl` will be as maintainable as `Window` however, when it comes to having control over your display is basically painless, compared to `Window`.