# Where is gacutil.exe in Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, 64-bit, windows-10, gacutil

I've got **Windows 10 Pro 64 bit**, **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015** and the **full Windows 10 SDK package** but **I'm not able to find gacutil.exe** in:

- **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 subdirectories**
- **Windows 10 SDK subdirectories**
- **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET subdirectories**
- **C:\Windows\System32**
- **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**
- **C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies subdirectories**
- **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies subdirectories**

Don't come tell me it's a duplicate, please. The other answers **don't actually answer my question**.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see the exe here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe"

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's not there.

Comment: look in the 4.6.1 or 4.6 folder. this depends on which .net SDK you have installed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**I had to use the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Developer Command Prompt.**

Unfortunately, Microsoft KB's are **outdated** and they usually give the wrong answers.

Go to **Start** -> **Visual Studio 2015** -> **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015**

Comment: Why is this not accessible through the regular (or Administrator) PowerShell?

Comment: @marijnz0r cause the SDK's path isn't included in system PATH. browse to the SDK path  - and it'll be available.

Answer (score 14):

If you want find gacutil location then Follow this:

1. Go to Start menu.
2. A-search  and find Developer Command Prompt
   or
   B-find and open Visual Studio 201_(2,3,5,7)  Folder
3. click Developer Command Prompt for vs201(2,3,5,7)
4. Type and enter:( where gacutil )
5. "Developer Command Prompt" will be return location of gacutil.exe

But if you want cache dll , location of gacutil  not necessary, Just run  "Developer Command Prompt" and type : gacutil /i "dll_path"

Answer (score 10):

In Windows 10, `gacutil.exe` is located here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe`

Note that the Framework directory `NETFX <version> Tools`, can be different; if you don't have 4.6.1 installed, you will have another version installed instead.

To find out where any EXE in your PATH is coming from, you can use the `where` utility:

[image: Screenshot showing how where utility in action.]

Syntax: `where <executable.exe>`

Comment: Kudos for the correct answer AND showing how you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

**I just installed the .NET 4.8 developer pack; gacutil is located at:**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools

**You can download the .NET 4.8 developer pack at:**

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer

*(I am running Win10 Pro 64-bit)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

Much thanks and appreciation to George & 'sbus' :)
Previously I'm unable to view dlls under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL even though there's no error during registration.

After changing to this latest .NET 4.8's gacutil, finally able to register and see the component properly in the said folder already.

The path where these files are placed is C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

The above happens when we try to migrate an existing Win7 client to Win10.
At the same time, we also found for some older/Win7 apps at the latest Win10, you'll need to re-install back the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package] (both 32-bit & 64-bit) in order to be backward compatible.

Good day & much thanks again :)