# Prism 6 and WPF4

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I'm build simple application with PRISM 6 and WPF. I want to pass EventArgs to my ViewModel, so far I have this code:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RotaryTableCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="MouseWheel"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The problem I have is in prism:InvokeCommandAction and I got this message: "The type 'invokeCommandAction' from assembly 'Prism.Wpf' is built with an older verision of Blend SDK, and is not supported in WPF4 project.

I realy don't know what should I do.

Comment: Not sure about exact prism implementation but in vanila WPF you have Parameter which you can bind args to.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024034/the-type-from-assembly-is-built-with-an-older-version-of-blend-sdk-and-is-not-su