# Why when adding new text the lines have empty lines between them?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

```
private void Println(string text, SolidColorBrush brush) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            RichTextBoxLogger.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(text) { Foreground = brush }));
        });

        private void Println(string text)
        {
            Println(text, Brushes.LawnGreen);
        }

        private void PrintMsg(string message)
        {
            Println($"[+] {message}", Brushes.Yellow);
        }

        private void PrintErr(Exception e)
        {
            Println($"[-] {e}", Brushes.Red);
        }
```

Using it

```
private void Fsw_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");

            string output = $"[*] {e.Name}: \"Deleted At : {time}\"";
            Println(output);
        }
```

The result is :

[image: lines added with empty lines between them]

I want to add this lines without empty lines between them.

Comment: Maybe because you are adding paragraphs not lines? Also, you can check if synchronization is required before making unnecessary `Dispatcher.Invoke` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a break from occurring between two consecutive paragraphs, you must set the `Paragraph.KeepWithNext` property to `true`:

```cs
var paragraphWithoutBreak = new Paragraph { KeepWithNext = true };
```

---

I don't recommend to use the heavy `RichTextBox` for your task. It will become slow when the output grows. Instead use a light `ListBox`. `ListBox` features UI virtualization and will significantly improve the performance. When you set `ListBoxItem.IsHitTestVisible` to `false`, the `ListBox` will look and feel like a read-only document. Define a DataTemplate for each message type to control the appearance of the output:

**ILogMessage.cs**

```cs
interface ILogMessage
{
  string Message { get; }
}
```

**ErrorMessage.cs**
A red message.

```cs
class ErrorMessage : ILogMessage
{
  // TODO::Implement interface and add a constructor that accepts a message.
}
```

**WarningMessage.cs**
A yellow message.

```cs
class WarningMessage : ILogMessage
{
  // TODO::Implement interface and add a constructor that accepts a message.
}
```

**InfoMessage.cs**
A green message.

```cs
class InfoMessage : ILogMessage
{
  // TODO::Implement interface and add a constructor that accepts a message.
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<ILogMessage> Messages { get; }
  
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeConmponent();
    this.Messages = new ObservableCollection<ILogMessage>();
  }

  private void WriteInfoLine(string message) 
    => this.Messages.Add(new InfoMessage(message));

  private void WriteWarningLine(string message) 
    => this.Messages.Add(new WarningMessage(message));

  private void WriteErrorLine(string message) 
    => this.Messages.Add(new ErrorMessage(message));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:InfoMessage}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"
                 Foreground="LawnGreen" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WarningMessage}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"
                 Foreground="Yellow" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ErrorMessage}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"
                 Foreground="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Messages}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
                Value="False" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683012/3141792) to know how to scroll the message view to the bottom when adding new items. You can use the example's `LogMessageBox` control (a `UserControl`) and replace the above `ListBox`.